# how to do instant update in BB RIM?

Tags: blackberry

I want to manually display a field.

```
public class Main_NewsDetail extends MainScreen {
private Custom_FontField slider;
private boolean a;

public Main_NewsDetail() {
    super(USE_ALL_WIDTH);

    slider = new Custom_FontField(
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider_thumb_normal.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider_progress_normal.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider_base_normal.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider_thumb_focused.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider_progress_focused.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider_base_focused.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider_thumb_pressed.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider_progress_pressed.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider_base_pressed.png"), 35, 10, 5,
            5, FOCUSABLE);
    if(a)
    add(slider);


}

public class Custom_NewsDetailBottom extends Manager implements
        FieldChangeListener {


    Custom_NewsDetailBottom() {
        super(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL
                | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);
        Background background = BackgroundFactory
                .createBitmapBackground(bg);
        setBackground(background);
        fontbtn = new Custom_ButtonField(font, fontactive, fontactive) {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                a = !a;   <-- here is to control field display
                return true;
            }
        };
        fontbtn.setChangeListener(this);
        add(fontbtn);


    }

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        Field field = getField(0);
        layoutChild(field, font.getWidth(), font.getHeight());
        setPositionChild(field, getGap(), 5);



        width = Math.min(width, getPreferredWidth());
        height = Math.min(height, getPreferredHeight());
        setExtent(width, height);
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return 70;
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return Display.getWidth();
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        int rectHeight = getPreferredHeight();
        int rectWidth = getPreferredWidth();
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, rectWidth, rectHeight);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }

    private int getGap() {
        return ((getPreferredWidth() / 4) - font.getWidth()) / 2;
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if (field == sharebtn) {

        } else if (field == commentbtn) {
            Main.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Main_Comments());
        } else if (field == otherbtn) {
            Main.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Menu_Others());
        }
    }

    public boolean keyDown(int keycode, int status) {
        if (Keypad.key(keycode) == Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE) {
            delete(slider);
            return true;
        }
        return super.keyDown(keycode, status);
    }
}
}
```

Above is the code that display a screen. In fontbtn, When click will change the variable `true / false`. However, it cannot update instant to display the field `slider`.

`slider` is something like seekbar in `Android`. In android, when click then can `setvisibility` but not blackberry RIM, so how to control it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend not using variables with names like this if you can avoid it:

```java
private boolean a;
```

Try to give it a name that's more descriptive, as that will help us understand your code better.

Next, it looks like you are testing the variable `a` before it ever has a chance to change, in the `Main_NewsDetail` constructor.  So that won't work.  Maybe try this in the `Main_NewsDetail` class:

```java
/** separate boolean used because Field.isVisible() doesn't seem totally robust */
private boolean isSliderVisible = false;

private void setSliderVisible(boolean isVisible) {
   if (isVisible != isSliderVisible) {
      if (isVisible) {
          add(slider);
      } else {
          delete(slider);
          // but, we still retain the "slider" member variable, so it can be
          // added again later
      }
      isSliderVisible = isVisible;

      // I'm not actually sure that this is needed.  I include it because I can't run this code right now!
      invalidate();
   }  
}
```

Then, in your button click handler:

```java
fontbtn = new Custom_ButtonField(font, fontactive, fontactive) {
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
         setSliderVisible(!isSliderVisible);
         return true;
     }
};
```

Now, this code can work because your `Main_NewsDetail` has only one `Field` in it, the slider.  If there are actually multiple `Field` objects (which you probably will have), then you may need more complicated logic.  You may want to show the slider in the same location every time.  For that, you can record the `index` of the slider, in the list of all the `Main_NewsDetail`s fields (for example, is the slider the 1st field, the 2nd, the 5th?).  Then, instead of calling `add(slider)`, you would do:

```java
private void setSliderVisible(boolean isVisible) {
   if (isVisible != isSliderVisible) {
      if (isVisible) {
         insert(slider, sliderIndex);
```

You might need to make `Main_NewsDetail` a subclass of `Manager` and implement the `sublayout()` method.  That way, you can make sure that if `isSliderVisible`, you always lay out the slider in the same position.

Comment: variable `a` is just for testing and fast typing, soon will change. Yes, you were right, slider is number forth. How complicated the code if there is more than one field?

Comment: I just added the code, it works included `invalidate()`, thanks again

Comment: @AlanLai, great.  Did you **need** to include the call to `invalidate()`?  Does the code work without it?  I typed up my answer without being able to run on a simulator, so I included that call *just in case the field didn't display without it*.

Comment: I never try without calling `invalidate()`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling Manager's [invalidate](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#invalidate%28%29)-method to force a repaint for the managed area:

```
Marks this entire manager as requiring repainting.
Invoke this method to signal that this manager's entire region requires repainting.
```